# javascript array push issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the below object:

```
Configs = {};
Configs['category'] = [];
Configs['category']['prod1'] = [];
Configs['category']['prod1'].hosts ={
  'table': {
    'count': 'total_remaining',
    'specs': [
      {
        'name': 'Test 1',
        'code': 'BrandName.Cat.Code.[X].Price'
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

I am trying to create an array of elements to be requested from the database using the code below:

```
var data = Configs["category"]["prod1"].hosts.table;
var count = [data.count];
var names = data.specs;
var namesArray = names.map(function(names) {
  var str = names['code'];
  var requiredPortion = str.split("[X]");
  var newStr = requiredPortion[0];
      return newStr;
  });
requestData = namesArray.reduce(function(a,b){if(a.indexOf(b)<0)a.push(b);return a;},[]); //remove duplicates
requestData.push(count);
console.log(count);
console.log(requestData);
```

The desired output is:

```
["BrandName.Cat.Code.", "total_remaining"]
```

But, when executing my code I am getting the following output:

```
["BrandName.Cat.Code.", Array[1]]
```

I am attaching a fiddle [link](https://jsfiddle.net/fLLu2cmf/) for this. I guess the issue is with array push function usage. Please help.

Comment: Your fiddle link seems to be working

Comment: Was doing a trial and error. Just noticed I got it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just have to remove the square bracket outside the count variable initialization. Try:

```
var count = data.count;
```

Instead of:

```
var count = [data.count];
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fLLu2cmf/1/) updated.

Answer (score 0):

Replace var `count = [data.count];` with `count = Object.keys(data).length`

Maybe this helps.

Comment: why should I do that?

Comment: It may be another alternative because I tried with node.js' console, there var count = Object.keys(data).length works but var count = data.count; does not work.

Comment: Sorry my naming was confusing. I don't want to take the count. Just needed that array.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I figured it out.